# How to crawl classified websites

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to write a crawler with Scrapy to crawl a classified-type (target) site and fetch information from the links on the target site. The tutorial on [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/intro/tutorial.html) only helps me get the links from the target URL but not the second layer of data gathering that I seek. Any leads?

So for instance, target site would be:

```
start_url = "http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/cta"
```

and for all the links on the target site I want to go to each listing and get the price, seller, location, phone or email

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: Hi James. We try to encourage new users here (well, everyone really) to show their research. I expect that if you search here, GitHub and the web generally you'll find some sort of scraper for CraigsList. However, bear in mind CraigsList the company may take a dim view of scrapers, since running one is an attempt to procure data for free that someone else has spent a lot of time and money assembling. At the very least you need to put pauses between scrapes, and accept being IP blocked if that's CraigLists's decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()




class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["newyork.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/cta"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//div[@class="content"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = CompItem()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('.//p[@class="row"]/span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="pl"]/a/text()').extract().
            item['price'] = site.xpath('.//p[@class="row"]/span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
            item['location'] = site.xpath('.//p[@class="row"]/span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[@class="pnr"]/small/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
            return items
```

Comment: Thanks John for your help. It worked!